# Check if I sign in as an IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible somehow to check if I signed in as an IAM user or AWS account root user on https://console.aws.amazon.com ? I can't see any information in My Account section.

Comment: Shoudn't there be your IAM username displayed in the top bar of the console, to the right to the Region name?

Answer (score 0):

The way I figure this out is to look at the top right of the console.

If you just see a username then you're using a root user.

If you're seeing a `username@account-id` you're not a root user.